# It is not correctly? Review Present Continuous and Present Simply

Tags: grammar, present-tense

I'm learning english and I have problem with translation name of sound: "Tell Me When We're Having Fun". I not understand why was Present Continuous form of tense used?
Is it not should use Present Simple (exactly "have fun"), as used definition in a general sense (have fun) or it means that action takes place right now and this form emphasize it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This question would be better on the English Language Learners site)

It depends on the kind of condition.

If it is a punctual condition, then we use the simple present:

> Tell me when you get here.

But here the condition is that something is happening and continuing to happen at that time:

> Tell me when we're having fun.